# Stored passwords in plaintext?

Tags: php, passwords

I was working on testing some projects , and theres a service in site that let you enter your id and its gets your passwords , is this mean that the backend stored the passwords in plaintext and not encrypted  ?

Comment: When you say id do you mean username? Also do you mean the passwords for that site?

Comment: @shn , id = username yes , passwords for the users that are registered in site

Comment: Why would it not be encrypted? Encryption works both ways, it is hashes you cannot get the original password from. By the way, if you can get your passwords with just an id that would indicate that the encryption used is not very secure.

Comment: Possibly, but it doesn't matter. Even if they're not plain text, they're recoverable, and passwords should never be recoverable.

Comment: @AlexHowansky It sounds like a password-manager so that would be a valid use-case. Without having to send a personal key however, I would not recommend using it :-)

Comment: @jeroen _"let you enter your id and its gets your passwords"_ Yeah that's iffy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily - the backend may store encrypted passwords and decrypt them with some predetermined key when they are retrieved.

However, this is still a pretty weak solution from a security standpoint. A proper approach would be to just store the encrypted/hashed (and salted!) password and be able to check if a given input matches it, without the ability to retrieve the clear-text password.

Comment: Do not foget about salt https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)